# How to load the data in asp:grid after providing filters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have to load the data in `asp:grid` after filtering from two `asp:dropdown` list. For example following is the dropdown lists:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlb" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    CssClass="ddlb" Width="100px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
                    DataTextField="MonthYearName" DataValueField="MonthYear" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="Changed">
                </asp:DropDownList>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProdDB %>" SelectCommand="# some sql query">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="asd" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    CssClass="ddlb" Width="100px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" 
                    DataTextField="MonthYearName" DataValueField="MonthYear" 
                    onselectedindexchanged="SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProdDB %>" SelectCommand="# some queries">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now, When i am loading the page. It shows the above defined dropdown list. What i want to know is "how should i load the data in `aspx grid` using the above two dropdown filter ?".

For example i choose `A` option from the first dropdown then it filter the result on the basis of it and the data will display on `grid` and so on...

Please tell me how should i connect the grid with these two dropdown list ?

How should i filter it ?

Comment: Actually i don't have such kind of problem ..just asking for the tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a grid and two drop down on the page.
Place an SQL Data Source

Provide two parameters to the sql datasource select command

Attached that sqldatasource to the gridview

Bind the two parameters of the SQLDataSource to the the two Dropdown boxes.

Comment: Please explain the 3rd and 4th point. I am not able to understand hot to attached the gridview to sql and how to build the parameters of the SQLData source

Comment: @AmitPal, looks like you are too novice to understand this. Probably you need a proper tutorial. But this site is not designed for tutorial. To populate data in gridview, it must fetch data from somewhere. That source source of data is usually sqldatasource which acts as an adaptor between gridview and the database. Bind mean, connect the parameter to the control.